# Comparing contents of lists ignoring order

Tags: python, list, equality

assuming I have a class shown below:

```py
class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.A = a
```

and I have 2 lists of these objects

```py
# sorry this is a bad example, plz look at the bottom
a = [OBJ(1), OBJ(0), OBJ(20), OBJ(-1)]
b = [OBJ(20), OBJ(-1), OBJ(1), OBJ(0)]
```

how do I prove that these 2 lists' contents are the same?
I have tried to use the sorted() method but it doesn't seem to work because you cannot logically compare 2 objects. Does anyone have a quick and efficient way of solving this? Thank you!

edit:
sorry the 2 lists are a bad example. When i mean the same i mean they are both refering to the same object. so:

```py
a = OBJ(1)
b = OBJ(-1)
c = OBJ(20)

x = [a,b,c]
y = [c,a,b]
```

how do i prove x and y are the same?

Comment: What does it _mean_ for the contents to be "the same"? With the code you posted, `(OBJ(0) == OBJ(0)) is False`

Comment: sorry I meant they are supposed to refer to the same object, I've edited the question

Comment: Do you mean refer to the same object, or the objects have the same input? Ive edited my answer to include if you mean to check if they point to the exact same object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `__eq__` and `__lt__` methods to allow you to sort the objects and then compare them:

```
class OBJ:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.A = a
    
    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if not isinstance(other, OBJ):
            # don't attempt to compare against unrelated types
            return NotImplemented

        return self.A == other.A
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
         return self.A < other.A

a = [OBJ(1), OBJ(0), OBJ(20), OBJ(-1)]
b = [OBJ(20), OBJ(-1), OBJ(1), OBJ(0)]
```

test:

```
sorted(a) == sorted(b)
Output: True
```

**Edit:**

The comment in the question made it so that you wanted to check that the objects were exactly the same, not just the same inputs. To do this, just use `id()` to see if they point to the same exact object

example:

```
a = OBJ(1)
b = OBJ(-1)
c = OBJ(20)

x = [a,b,c]
y = [c,a,b]
sorted([id(temp) for temp in x]) == sorted([id(temp) for temp in y])
Output: True
```

however...

```
a = OBJ(1)
b = OBJ(-1)
c = OBJ(20)
d = OBJ(20) # Same input value as c, but a different object

x = [a,b,c]
y = [d,a,b]
sorted([id(temp) for temp in x]) == sorted([id(temp) for temp in y])
Output: False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could compare 2 stand-in lists that are `sorted()` based on your attribute `A`:

```
>>>print(sorted([o.A for o in a]) == sorted([o.A for o in b]))
True
```